# TYPO3 6.1 : config.disablePrefixComment=1 not working

Tags: comments, typo3

Hello I'm wondering why this setting is not working in my TYPO3 6.1

I'm trying to remove typo3's automatic comments like

```
<!-- header end-->
        <!--###main zerogrid### end --></div>
    <!--###body2### end --></div>
<!--###body1### end --></div>
    <div class="body3"><!--###body3### begin -->
        <div class="main zerogrid"><!--###main zerogrid### begin -->
```

and so on.

[image]

FYI, I wrote config.disablePrefixComment=1 in the main TS template setup.

I read typo3 latest reference [docs](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#disableprefixcomment) but it's only a simple boolean setting.

Here the TS setup:

```
config.disablePrefixComment = 1


config.no_cache = 1


config.baseURL = http://xxxx.yyyy.net


# Main TEMPLATE cObject for the BODY
temp.mainTemplate = TEMPLATE
temp.mainTemplate {
# Feeding the content from the Auto-parser to the TEMPLATE cObject:
template =< plugin.tx_automaketemplate_pi1
# Select only the content between the <body>-tags
workOnSubpart = DOCUMENT_BODY
  subparts.content < styles.content.get
}

# Main TEMPLATE cObject for the HEAD
temp.headTemplate = TEMPLATE
temp.headTemplate {
# Feeding the content from the Auto-parser to the TEMPLATE cObject:
template =< plugin.tx_automaketemplate_pi1
# Select only the content between the <head>-tags
workOnSubpart = DOCUMENT_HEADER

}

page = PAGE
page.typeNum = 0

page.10 < temp.mainTemplate

# Copying the content from TEMPLATE for <head>-section:
page.headerData.100 < temp.headTemplate

page.bodyTag >

page.bodyTagCObject = TEXT
page.bodyTagCObject.value= page1
page.bodyTagCObject.wrap = <body id="|">

plugin.tx_automaketemplate_pi1 {
 content = FILE
 content.file = fileadmin/templates/zp/index.html
 elements {
  BODY.all = 1
  BODY.all.subpartMarker = DOCUMENT_BODY
  HEAD.all = 1
  HEAD.all.subpartMarker = DOCUMENT_HEADER
  HEAD.rmTagSections = title
  TD.all = 1
  TABLE.all = 1
  TR.all = 1
  DIV.all = 1
 }
 relPathPrefix = fileadmin/templates/zp/
 relPathPrefix.A = ./
}
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: What comment do you want ot remove?

Comment: yes see above I add a sample from html source

Answer (score 0):

Browse with the template analysis your ts. Maybe it gets overwritten somehow?

Comment: Hello ScubaBen, thanks for your prompt reply. I did a check through object browser and I found this setting, as you can see above.

Comment: Some reports say, that it doesnt't work, if it is late in the configuration. Try to put it on top of your config (before RealUrl initializes) Have a look here: http://pastebin.com/4twvTM9h and here: http://professionelles-webdesign-berlin.de/2011/10/disableprefixcomment-1-funktioniert-nicht/

Comment: I put the line at the top as you suggested but nothing has changed (I'm not using realURL at the moment).

Comment: What extensions / static TS do you have running?

Comment: I'm using only the css_styled_content. See above for the TS setup.

Answer (score 0):

This setting will only affect comments that are touched by `TYPO3 CMS`. If you do not replace the blocks, nothing will happen and those comments stay.
The comments are inserted by `automaketemplate` and have nothing to do with `TYPO3 CMS`. `TYPO3 CMS` just sees the parsed template file with all comments and will remove the comments of the replace blocks.
Untouched blocks remain untouched.